# Can't browse samba share, get a "Cannot retrieve share list from server" error

Tags: 10.10, samba

I'm having a lot of issues with Samba and trying to connect it up with a MyWorldBook NAS drive.

Running Maverick

- I have the Samba 2:3.5.4 package installed that the distro came loaded with.
- I can see the Windows Network and see MyBookWorld attached.
- I click on it, it says it's opening, then hangs, and brings up "Cannot retrieve share list from server.
- I've tried to browse on other computers, Mac and W7, and it works fine.

If anyone can lend a hand or some advice I would truly appreciate it. I had Samba working in Lucid and it would work, so I'm scratching my head on this one.

Comment: Have you tried changing the workgroup in "/etc/smb.conf"?

Answer (score 1):

```
gksudo gedit /etc/samba/smb.conf
```

Check your workgroup

```
# Change this to the workgroup/NT-domain name your Samba server will part of
workgroup = WORKGROUP
```

Change if needed.

Keep me informed